# Reference type assignments across few variables

Tags: c#, .net, reference

The question I'm going to ask puzzled me only because I was diving into some C# details. Consider the following code:

```
    public class Node 
    {
         public int Data {get;set;}
    }
  
   var a = new Node() { Data = 1 }; // address in memory 0x600000
   var b = new Node() { Data = 2 }; // address in memory 0x700000
   var c = new Node() { Data = 3 }; // address in memory 0x800000

   a = b;  // variable a holds a reference to the memory location of b -> 0x700000
   b = c;  // variable b holds a reference to the memory location of c -> 0x800000
```

If I do

```
b.Data = 4;
```

here is my output

```
Console.WriteLine(a.Data);  //2
Console.WriteLine(b.Data);  //4
Console.WriteLine(c.Data);  //4
```

Here, I was expecting 4 to be printed out for all three variables. Why? Because, from code perspective `a` has a reference to `b`, `b` has a reference to `c`, hence `a` and `c` both have a reference to exactly the same memory location - which is wrong.

Final words or how I interpreted this to myself:
`a` has as a value the address of object `b`,
`b` has as a value the address of object `c`

`b` and `c` are located in memory in two different locations so when you are applying a change to `b`, will be visible when you access it via variable `b` or `c` as effectively you are changing the value of variable `c` (`b` and `c` are referring to the same memory address space where data will be stored in). When you access a value via `a` those won't be visible even in code you have a reference to `b`. Effectively, here `a` is not changed at all, hence we are getting the value where variable `b` is pointing to.

Is my understanding correct or do you have a cleaner explanation?

Comment: `address in memory 0x600000` <-- Where is this coming from?

Comment: "_Because, from code perspective `a` has a reference to `b`, `b` has a reference to `c`, hence `a` and `c` both have a reference to exactly the same memory location_" -> No, variables reference objects, not other references.

Answer (score 7):

When you do:

```
a = b;
```

`a` is now pointing to the memory location where `b` is also pointing, but when the following line executes:

```
b = c;
```

Now `b` and `c` are both pointing to the same memory location, so when we update the `b` it is changed to the same memory location where both `b` and `c` are pointing too, but `a` is not pointing to that memory location so it won't see that change as references are passed by value.

If we want the change to be reflected for all the reference variables then we should be using pass by reference. [You can read more about the difference between pass by value and pass by reference to get more understanding](http://developmentpassion.blogspot.com/2015/09/misconceptions-regarding-pass-by-value.html).

See the following to help understand that when `b` is assigned `c` it is disconnected from it's original memory location and now `b` and `c` both reference to common memory location but not `a`:

[image]

The behaviour you are expecting can be acheived if you assign them on single line like :

```
a = b = c;
```

Now when you update the `Data` using the `c` variable, it would be reflection for all the 3 variables.

Please look at the following diagram to get idea what is happening in this case:

[image]

Comment: Is exactly what I have explained